# Existence of a Perfect matching in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

how to find whether a given graph has a perfect matching or not?? I read that the degree should be atleast n/2 for all the vertices to be a perfect matching..But can anyone give the necessary and sufficient condition... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tutte's Theorem characterizes the graphs with a perfect matching.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem

It states that some graph $G = (V, E)$ has a perfect matching if and only if for any subset $U \subseteq V$, the graph induced by $V - U$ (that is, by removing the vertices of $U$ from $G$) has at most $|U|$ connected components with an odd number of vertices.